# How to globally override a pythonPackage in nix

Tags: python, nix

I'm trying to override a python package (uvloop) globally, in nix, such that black sees the override.

uvloop (python package) tests fail for me because I'm working behind a firewall.  I can build things that use uvloop by editing the nixpkgs derivation directly (ugh) to set `doCheck = false`.

I'm trying to encode this in an overlay, but without success - the overlay is read (e.g., syntax errors cause failure), but nothing I do in the overlay actually stop the tests from running.

I've tried following tips from https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Overlays, https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#how-to-override-a-python-package-using-overlays and [How to use custom python with existing packages - nix derivation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658367/how-to-use-custom-python-with-existing-packages-nix-derivation) (overlaying python using packageOverrides; with pythonOverrides; and with and without using overridePythonAttrs); both for python3 and python39; but with no success.

E.g.,

```
self: super: {
  python3 = super.python3.override {
    packageOverrides = pyself: pysuper: {
      uvloop = pysuper.uvloop.overrideAttrs (_: {
        doCheck = false;
      });
    };
  };
}
```

For bonus points, I'd like to achieve this for all instances of python package uvloop - not just the one in 3.9 - but I'll take any help I can get.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me. It applies a patch to twitch-chat-downloader (Python app) and a patch to twitch-python (Python library used by twitch-chat-downloader). `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.twitch-chat-downloader` installed a patch copy of twitch-chat-downloader which uses a patched copy of twitch-python.

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    python3 = pkgs.python3.override {
      packageOverrides = python-self: python-super: {
        twitch-python = python-super.twitch-python.overrideAttrs (attrs: {
          patches = (attrs.patches or []) ++ [
            ./twitch-allow-no-token.patch
          ];
        });
      };
    };

    twitch-chat-downloader = pkgs.twitch-chat-downloader.overrideAttrs (attrs: {
      patches = (attrs.patches or []) ++ [
        ./twitch-chat-downloader-no-oauth.patch
      ];
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue with the same package. I wasn't able to source an answer from the Nix docs, but I *think* this is what's happening, and why your example doesn't work.

`python3` is just an alias of `python39`, in the same way that `python3Packages` is an alias of `python39Packages` (see [this doc page](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/languages-frameworks/python.section.md#interpreters-interpreters).) When overriding `python3`, you're overriding the value of `python39`, but the result is then stored back in the `python3` variable instead of the alias - so other Nix code which goes directly through `python39` instead of the `python3` alias still sees the non-overridden package set.

#### A working way

The way that worked for me was to override the value of `python39` specifically, and leave `python3` as an alias pointing to the new overridden package set:

```hs
self: super: {
  python39 = super.python39.override {
    packageOverrides = pyself: pysuper: {
      uvloop = pysuper.uvloop.overrideAttrs (_: {
        doCheck = false;
      });
    };
  };
}
```